# Is there a nice way to define discrete enriched categories?

Tags: ct.category-theory, enriched-category-theory

In the setting of classical category theory, one defines the **discrete category** associated to a set $X$ as the category $X_\mathsf{disc}$ having the elements of $X$ as its objects and only identities as morphisms. This extends to a functor $\mathsf{disc}\colon\mathsf{Sets}\longrightarrow\mathsf{Cats}$, sitting in a quadruple adjunction
$$
\pi_0\dashv\mathsf{disc}\dashv\mathrm{Obj}\dashv\mathsf{indisc}\colon\mathsf{Cats}\overset{\rightleftarrows}{\rightleftarrows}\mathsf{Sets}.
$$

Passing now to $\mathcal{V}$-categories, is there a nice way to associate a “discrete $\mathcal{V}$-category” to an object of $\mathcal{V}$?

Comment: Incidentally, for $\mathcal{V}$ a monoidal category with an initial object $\varnothing_{\mathcal{V}}$ and given $V\in\mathrm{Obj}(\mathcal{V})$, one could try to define $V_{\mathsf{disc}}$ as the $\mathcal{V}$-category whose objects are morphisms $x\colon\mathbf{1}_{\mathcal{V}}\longrightarrow V$ of $\mathcal{V}$, and where, for each $x,y\in\mathsf{Obj}(V_{\mathsf{disc}})$, we have

$$
\textbf{Hom}_{V_{\mathsf{disc}}}(x,y)
\overset{\mathrm{def}}{=}
\begin{cases}
    \mathbf{1}_{\mathcal{V}}     &\text{if $x=y$,}\\
    \varnothing_{\mathcal{V}}    &\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: However, while this definition successfully recovers discrete categories when $\mathcal{V}=(\mathsf{Sets},\times,\mathrm{pt})$, it fails to recover e.g. the discrete $2$-category associated to a category when $\mathcal{V}=(\mathsf{Cats},\times,\mathsf{pt})$. It also seems to be an uninteresting notion for most other enrichments...

Comment: I'm not sure you can use this definition, but. Let $\cal K$ be a bicategory. An object $E$ (E as "ensemble") is called *bidiscrete* if each hom-category ${\cal K}(X,E)$ is equivalent to a discrete one (spelled out: for every two parallel arrows $f,g : X \to E$, there exists at most one 2-cell between them, and this cell is invertible).

Comment: I don't understand why you say this definition fails for $(Cats,\times)$. It seems to me that it produces exactly what I would want to call the discrete $2$-category on a set. Maybe you should clarify what you want this construction to do ?

Comment: Arguably it's not reasonable to expect to get a discrete $V$-enriched category from an object of $V$ rather than a set, since a $V$-category has a set of objects.  So you'll have to do something like you suggest to make an object of $V$ into a set first.  If you want a meaningful "discrete category" on an object of $V$, you need something like $V$-internal categories, or $W$-enriched fibrations for some monoidal fibration $W$ over $V$.

Comment: @SimonHenry The idea is to associate a discrete $\mathcal{V}$-category to an object of $\mathcal{V}$, so in this case we would want a discrete $2$-category on a category, rather than a set.

Comment: Ah sorry, I missed that.

Comment: @MikeShulman Thank you, this is very sensible. Do you know of a good definition in these two contexts?

Comment: @SimonHenry No worries! Rather, thank you for considering this question :)

Comment: Emily, The definition for internal categories is the same as in the case $\mathcal V=\mathtt{Sets}$, that is, we use a left adjoint to the forgetful functor. This always exists, as does the right adjoint, see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3990338/does-the-internal-category-forgetful-functor-have-both-adjoints/3990390#3990390.

Comment: @KevinArlin Thank you, this is excellent!

Comment: For enriched internal/indexed categories, see Definition 3.8 and Remark 3.11 of [Enriched indexed categories](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/28/21/28-21abs.html).

Comment: @MikeShulman Thank you!